# Adding a linked object to another object in C# ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a model as follows:

```
public class Analyst
{
    public int AnalystId { get; set; }
    public string AnalystName { get; set; }
    public string CorpId { get; set; }
    public string TeamLeader { get; set; }
    public string TLCorpId { get; set; }
    public IList<Objective> Objectives { get; set; }
    public IList<ObScore> ObScores { get; set; }
}

public class Objective
{
    public int ObjectiveId { get; set; }
    public int AnalystId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public Analyst Analyst { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to find a specific Objective which I can do with:

```
Objective objective = db.Objectives.Find(id);
```

...however I would also like to include the Analyst associated with the objective, so I ca reference a property on the oinked Analyst object:

```
if (objective.Analyst.TLCorpId != tl)
```

But when I'm trying to add the analyst object I get an error:

```
Objective objective = db.Objectives.Include(x => x.Analyst).Find(id);
```

> `System.Linq.IQueryable<Objectives.Models.Objective>` does not contain a definition for 'Find' and no extension method 'Find'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   `System.Linq.IQueryable<Objectives.Models.Objective>` could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Is there any way around this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method [`Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) defined on [`DbSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696460%28v=vs.113%29.aspx). Method [`Include`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696785%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) is defined on base class [`DbQuery<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696530%28v=vs.113%29.aspx). And problem here is that `Include` returns instance of base class, i.e. `DbQuery<T>` which don't have method `Find` (lambda-based include is just syntax sugar for calling same string-based include method). And even casting will not help you here, because new instance of base class is created internally:

```
public DbQuery<TResult> Include(string path)
{
    return new DbQuery<TResult>(this._internalQuery.Include(path));
}
```

So, use `SingleOrDefault` to get entity by id

```
Objective objective = db.Objectives.Include(x => x.Analyst)
                                   .SingleOrDefault(x => x.ObjectiveId == id);
```

NOTE: One difference here is that `Find` first checks if entity already exists in context before making database query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

Objective objective = db.Objectives.Find(id).Where(y=>y.Analyst.TLCorpId != tl).First();

Dont forget to check for nulls